# Should i use Javascript, CSS or what to hide an image rendered by a control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reportviewer, server-side

I would like to hide the background image of the ReportView control which is `toolbar_bk.png`
By saying hide actually i would like to set it to none.

So how could i easily do it? Server side, CSS, Javascript or even better JQUERY?
I am totally lost with this one.

Here is the rendered part

```
<div id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewer1_ctl05" 
  style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;border-bottom:1px #CCCCCC Solid;
  background-color:#F7F7F7;
  background-image:url(/domain-name.com/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?
  OpType=BackImage&Version=10.0.40219.329&
  Color=%23F7F7F7&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.toolbar_bk.png);">
```

Comment: All are possibilities, but this is what CSS is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want. Here's an answer nevertheless..

Wrap them with their own div. Let's give that div a class of "wrapper". on the css side paste this:

.wrapper * {
background-image: none;
}

Comment: I, above, assume you don't know beforehand what those ids="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewer1_ctl05" will be when they get to your page. I also assume you have control of the page where they'll be inserted.

Comment: oh, write. wasn't understanding the actual problem then.

Comment: just place !important after the style

Comment: that would be, and I'm sorry for putting all of these into their own comment.... so, that would be .wrapper * {background-image: none !important;}

Comment: That would work in some browsers.  IE 6 of course doesn't let you, but maybe the OP doesn't care about that browser.  This is definitely the best answer if you don't need to support older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that it's always CSS what hides your element or shows your background etc. You just can put it inline, into an external file or create it dynamically via a script language (i.e. JavaScript), eventually by use of a JavaScript library as jQuery.

To your question: Just don't create the inline style serverside, and everything is well.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you would simply do this:

```
$('#ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewer1_ctl05').css('background-image', 'none');
```

With just plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewer1_ctl05').style.backgroundImage = 'none';
```

With css in the page or in external style sheet:

```
#ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewer1_ctl05 { background-image:none !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Best option -- Configure the server control to not set a background image.
2. If #1 is not possible, you could write JavaScript to manipulate the HTML after it loads.

Here's a jQuery example if you need to use option 2:

```
$('[id~="ReportViewer1"]').css('background-image', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `addClass()` function as follows

```
<style>
            .report
            {
                background-color: #D6E3F3;
                /* background-image: url("/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=BackImage&Version=10.0.30319.1&Color=%23ECE9D8&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.toolbar_bk.png");*/
                border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
                font-family: Verdana;
                font-size: 8pt;
            }
            </style>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewer1_ctl05').removeAttr('style');
        $('#ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ReportViewer1_ctl05').addClass('report');
    });
</script>
```